# Trying to Make an Accurate Model of a Stratocaster

Tags: guitar, stratocaster

I'm refining a 3D model of a Fender Stratocaster and I have a question about the way the neck is configured. I don't know much about electric guitars (I play classical), although, after a visit to fender.com, I'm learning fast. On the model, the top level of the neck is slightly straighter than underneath -- well, it's hard to describe succinctly, so here's a picture:
[image]

Was the original modeler just sloppy (they were with some other parts), or is this for real?

Comment: Another guitar with a zero fret? great news! Yes, I'm serious. they're not common enough.

Comment: Are your green and blue lines perpendicular to the frets?

Comment: Yes, doctor. I did a screen grab of the model from directly overhead, then imported the image into PS to add the lines and text.

Comment: Yes, What I called "zero fret" is actually the nut. Like I said,I'm learning.

Comment: VLQ image, but it doesn't look like it @DrMayhem - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrxvS.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  how to build instruments (or models of instruments) is not included in the topics - this is not a a music question .

Comment: Sorry. I thought music.stackexchange was likely to include luthiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that diagram, it doesn't look like there is any difference in rake - it looks simply like you have not centred the neck correctly in your image.

While string lengths will all be slightly different, for intonation, as far as a standard neck goes, treat them all as identical length. The neck just has a taper.

Comment: Thank you. I suspect the original model was based on an image that wasn't quite overhead.